# How create list of string array in managed C++/CLI

Tags: arrays, list, c++-cli, managed-c++

In **managed C++/CLI** we create a list of string like below :

```
List<String^>^ ls = gcnew List<String^>();
```

And we create an array of string like below :

```
cli::array<String^> ^arr = gcnew cli::array<String^>{};
```

Now how create a list of string array in managed C++/CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   List<cli::array<String^>^>^ ls = gcnew List<cli::array<String^>^>();
```

Comment: Hi, please consider adding some explanation, as the answer right now is good, but too short.